# Неблокирующий прогресс индикатор

Tags: android, java

Есть ли в Android неблокирующий прогресс индикатор? Чтобы показать загрузку одного фрагмента. При этом пользователь может что-то делать на других фрагментах. Я нашел класс для прогресса:

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setMessage(message);
progress.show();
```

Но он блокирует весь activity, он мне не подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Заметки о ProgressDialog или как правильно показать прогресс выполнения](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/119023/)

Comment: Это именно то, что я искал.